# Modal Popup not working with AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have an autocompleteextender that displays the list of questions. In the same textbox, when I type something and click on "Search" button, a pop-up should be opened and select category. I am using modalpopupextender for the popup. But the modelPopup does notopen while using autocomplete extender.At the same time without auto complete extender it will work

Answer (score 7):

If you've tried to use the AutoCompleteExtender inside a ModalPopupExtender, you'll notice that the auto-complete options show behind the modal popup. 
This is a Z-index problem in which the ModalPopupExtender overrides all other controls. 
If you check the modal's Z-index you'll see that it uses 100001 for its foreground element, so use something higher like 10000001.

Use this code snippet:

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="ace" runat="server" OnClientShown="ShowOptions">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ShowOptions(control, args)
    {
        control._completionListElement.style.zIndex = 10000001;
    }
</script>
```